# SSRS Full Text Justification

Tags: reporting-services

I've read dozens of threads about this subject and i know it is not possible to justify text in reporting services as in Word, Excel, Crystal Reports, etc. ..

I also know that it is unacceptable that in 2013 Microsoft has not put this option available, but I really have to solve this problem in one way or another ...

So, as I said, after reading dozens of threads on this subject, I concluded that my only option is to make a custom report item... but the problem is I cannot do it because it's to complex to me...

Is there anyone who has built a custom report item for this purpose and it's kind enough to share it?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm afraid your "can someone help me build X" request (however nicely put) isn't in scope for SO as per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Your options are probably limited to Googling for tutorials, hiring someone to do it for you, or ... building it yourself ;)

Comment: What exactly is "this subject" and "this purpose"? I can't see the question here.

Comment: The question was pretty clear IMHO: "how to build a custom report item that enables fully justified text". The answer does fall outside the scope of SO though.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of Googling shows that there are third-party products that can provide this additional functionality.

Aspose is one example: http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfreportingservices/Justify+FullJustify+Text+Alignment